# Python gearman basic example error

Tags: python, gearman, python-gearman

I am trying a vaery basic example of string reversal using Python gearman module
MY localhost has been set up using IIS on port 4730
However i am getting the error

```
raise UnknownCommandError(missing_callback_msg)
UnknownCommandError: Could not handle command: 'GEARMAN_COMMAND_TEXT_COMMAND' - {'raw_text': 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r'}
```

**Client.py**

```
    import gearman
    #  setup client, connect to Gearman HQ
    gm_client = gearman.GearmanClient(['localhost:4730'])
    print 'Sending job...'
    request = gm_client.submit_job('reverse', 'Hello World!')
    print "Result: " + request.result
```

**Worker.py**

```
    import gearman
    gm_worker = gearman.GearmanWorker(['localhost:4730'])
    #  define method to handled 'reverse' work
    def task_listener_reverse(gearman_worker, gearman_job):
            print 'reporting status'
            return reversed(gearman_job.data)
    gm_worker.set_client_id('your_worker_client_id_name')
    gm_worker.register_task('reverse', task_listener_reverse)
    gm_worker.work()
```

Any suggestions as to why this might occur and how to resolve the same

Comment: Which gearman server version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `return reversed(gearman_job.data)` try using `return ''.join([i for i in reversed(gearman_job.data[::1])])`.

Returning `reversed(...)` will give you a `Type Error`.

Answer (score 1):

Current versions of gearman have a different import structure. You need to say `from gearman.worker import GearmanWorker` and `from gearman.client import GearmanClient`.

In addition, the return should say `return ''.join([i for i in reversed(gearman_job.data[::1])])` to get a reversed string.